# Two way binding in react, like in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

In AngularJS I can do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="firstname">
    <h1>{{firstname}}</h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    $scope.lastname = "Doe";    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What is the equivalent way to do this in React?
Here is what I have tried:

```
var app = document.getElementById("app");



var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {text: ""};
  },
  change: function(e){
    var newValue = e.target.value;
    this.setState({text: newValue});
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.change} type="text"/>
        <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
      </div>
      );
  }
});


React.render(<Main />, app);
```

Is it the best way for implementing this?

This way seems to be a little slow. Can you suggest another way?

Comment: Yes, this seems like a reasonable way to do it. What do you mean this "seems" slow?

Comment: @azizpunjani It seems to my eye that updating the view on each change is slow. I understand that angular do the same, but maybe they have a better way instead of using onChange attribute

Comment: Thinking in React requires us to discontinue thought about two-way bindings, and start thinking about unidirectional data flow. Data flows up, events flow up. Also, read up on Reacts VDOM if you're concerned about rendering performance.

Comment: @lux data flows *down* :-)

Comment: @azizpunjani Yeah, clearly a typo -_- Good catch

Comment: I came to SO to ask the same question.
In the react quick start docs there's a form example:

    `handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }`

...

    `<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />`

Having in mind the concept of two way binding from angular... this way, of wiring events for every input to update the state... seems overkill!
Is this really the react way of doing things?